# Strange rendering issue with monogame/WinGL with HD7670M

Tags: xna, opengl, monogame

I'm having some strange rendering issues with latest monogame/winGL code as seen below;

[image]

As you can see the xna and tomspilmans [WinDX port](https://github.com/SickheadGames/MonoGame/tree/windesktop) seems just okay.

I'm having this problem on my laptop with a HD7670M and it doesn't exists on desktops (got a 7970 and 5970).

Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: Looks like a vertex alignment problem of some sort. Can you post a higher resolution image of GL screenshot?